# Multilevel XSLT grouping and eliminate duplicates on last level

Tags: xml, xslt

I have project generated by STM32CubeMX in [GPDSC](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Pack/html/pdsc_components_pg.html) format an I would like to convert it to Netbeans C project. Fortunately, both are XML, so I have written XSL transformation.

I'm grouping `component/@Cclass`, then grouping by `component/@Cgroup` and then I would like to print all distinct `file/@name` in this group.

Here is example source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<package>
<components>
    <component Cclass="CMSIS" Cgroup="CORE">
    <files>
        <file name="core_cm0.h"/>
    </files>
    </component>
    <component Cclass="Device" Cgroup="Startup">  
    <files>
        <file name="stm32f0xx.h"/>
    </files>
    </component>
    <component Cclass="Device" Cgroup="STM32Cube HAL" Csub="USART">
    <files>
        <file name="stm32f0xx_ll_usart.h"/>
        <file name="stm32f0xx_ll_rcc.h"/>
    </files>
    </component>
    <component Cclass="Device" Cgroup="STM32Cube HAL" Csub="RCC">
    <files>
        <file name="stm32f0xx_ll_cortex.h"/>
        <file name="stm32f0xx_ll_rcc.h"/>
    </files>
    </component>
</components>
</package>
```

Here is my XSL transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:key name="k1" match="component" use="@Cclass"/>
<xsl:key name="k2" match="component" use="concat(@Cclass, '|', @Cgroup)"/>
<xsl:key name="k3" match="file" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template name="file-classes" match="components">
    <xsl:for-each select="component[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', @Cclass)[1])]">
        <logicalFolder projectFiles="true">
        <xsl:attribute name="displayName"><xsl:value-of select="@Cclass" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', @Cclass)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', concat(@Cclass, '|', @Cgroup))[1])]">
            <logicalFolder projectFiles="true">
            <xsl:attribute name="displayName"><xsl:value-of select="@Cgroup" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('k2', concat(@Cclass, '|', @Cgroup))">
                <xsl:for-each select="files/file[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k3', @name)[1])]">
                    <xsl:sort select="@name" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('k3', @name)">
                        <itemPath><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></itemPath>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </logicalFolder>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </logicalFolder>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="package/components">
    <xsl:call-template name="file-classes"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<logicalFolder projectFiles="true" displayName="CMSIS">
  <logicalFolder projectFiles="true" displayName="CORE">
    <itemPath>core_cm0.h</itemPath>
  </logicalFolder>
</logicalFolder>
<logicalFolder projectFiles="true" displayName="Device">
  <logicalFolder projectFiles="true" displayName="Startup">
    <itemPath>stm32f0xx.h</itemPath>
  </logicalFolder>
  <logicalFolder projectFiles="true" displayName="STM32Cube HAL">
    <itemPath>stm32f0xx_ll_rcc.h</itemPath>
    <itemPath>stm32f0xx_ll_rcc.h</itemPath>
    <itemPath>stm32f0xx_ll_usart.h</itemPath>
    <itemPath>stm32f0xx_ll_cortex.h</itemPath>
  </logicalFolder>
</logicalFolder>
```

As you can see, two levels of grouping works but I have duplicate `itemPath` nodes, because in source XML, there are some `file` nodes multiple times, e.g. `stm32f0xx_ll_rcc.h`.

How can I remove duplicates? I'm little bit lost on the third level of grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to process the first occurrence of the "k3" group.

So change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('k3', @name)">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('k3', @name)[1]">
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.